# How to generate Java REST client from Spring REST Docs like it is generated from swagger.json?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, spring-restdocs

My team used swagger for documenting REST API.

As a QA engineer I was able to generate rest client from swagger.json that was published on remote server upon deploy and use the client for REST API integration testing.

Now we are about to switch from swagger to Spring REST Docs.

**QUESTION**:
Is there a way to generate java rest client from Spring REST Docs like it was possible for swagger?

If yes - how to do that?

If no - are there any alternative ways to get/generate REST API client.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a Spring Rest Docs extension now that generates an OpenAPI 2/3 spec which you can then use to do additional things - like generate a client

https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-api-spec